# Prove that if $n(a^2+b^2+c^2)=abc$ then $2\mid n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Is it true that if $n\in\mathbb N$ and the diophantine equation $$n(a^2+b^2+c^2)=abc,\\(a,b)=(b,c)=(c,a)=1\tag1$$ 
>   has positive integer solutions $a,b,c$, then $2\mid n$?

I can prove that $3\mid n:$

1) If $3\not\mid abc$ then $3\mid a^2+b^2+c^2,$ a contradiction.
2) If $3\mid abc,$ since $(a,b)=(b,c)=(c,a)=1$, we can assume that $3\mid a$ and $3\not \mid bc,$ then $3\not\mid a^2+b^2+c^2,$ hence $3\mid n.$

I can prove that equation $(1)$ has infinitely many solutions when $n=6,$  in fact, let $c=17,$ then it become a Pell's equation: $(12a-17b)^2-145b^2=-41616.$

I find some solutions to equation $(1)$:
$\{a,b,c,n\}=\{39,20,17,6\}\{52,29,15,6\}\{68,61,45,18\}\{87,80,61,24\}$

However, I cannot prove that $2\mid n.$ Thanks in advance!

Comment: observation: this is the same as proving exactly one of $a,b,c$ is even.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I wonder how to rule out that $a,b,c,n$ are all odd.

Comment: Have you tried taking a,b,c as of form 2k+1 etc and then look at the behaviour of both sides?

Comment: Also I wonder if induction would work here.

Comment: @Hecke i don't know. but if you can prove that exactly one of a,b,c is even(all cannot be since they are pairwise relatively co-prime), n must be even.

Comment: @quarkine I tried it but cannot find anything helpful.

Comment: @quarkine taking $2k+1$ is far inferior to checking $\mod 2$ and that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: By the way, from where does the equation come from?

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc This problem come from one of my friends, so maybe there exist a counterexample.

Comment: And where did your friend found this problem? Does it come from something geometrical? Or from a question of number theory? I am not saying this to say that it is not a good problem, just to understand better the equation.

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc Well, he only asked me if equation $(1)$ has integer solutions, I found some solutions, so I have answered his questions. But I have a hobby, when I saw a problem, I would think what can be discussed from this problem. When I solve $(1)$, I found that for all the solutions I can find, $n$ are even, but I cannot prove that, so I ask this question.

Comment: @Hecke This looks like a good way of doing... :-)

Comment: If we remove $(a,b)=(b,c)=(c,a)=1$ then $n=9,a=21,b=35,c=42$ is a solution to $(1)$, I think we cannot prove it only by $\mod something$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed true. We need the following well known fact:

> If $p\equiv3\pmod4$ is prime and $p\mid x^2+y^2$, then $p\mid x$ and
>   $p\mid y$.

We will prove that

**Theorem.** If $a,b,c$ is a solution to $(1)$, then exactly one of $a,b,c$ is divisible by $4$.

*Proof.*

First suppose $a,b,c$ are all odd. Then $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv3\pmod 4$, so has a prime divisor $p\equiv3\pmod 4$. Without loss of generality, suppose $p\mid a$.

Then $p\mid b^2+c^2$, so $p\mid b$ and $p\mid c$ which contradicts the condition $(a,b)=(b,c)=(c,a)=1$.

Therefore one of $a,b,c$ is even. Say $2\mid a$ and suppose $4\nmid a$. Then $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv6\pmod8$, which means it has a prime divisor $p\equiv3\pmod 4$. Again $p\mid b$ and $p\mid c$, contradiction.

So we should have $4\mid a$. $\square$

In this case, $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv2\pmod 4$, which means $4\nmid a^2+b^2+c^2$. Therefore, $2\mid n$.

Comment: Well done! Thanks:)